# Limit of integral of exponentials to delta function

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

I have an integral of the type:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\kappa \int_{-\infty}^t d\tau e^{-\kappa |t-\tau|} e^{f(t-\tau)}
\end{equation}
where $f(t-\tau)$ is a generic function such that $f(0)=0$. I am interested in two limits:

$\bullet$ $\kappa \rightarrow \infty$

In this case, is it correct to assume $e^{-\kappa |t-\tau|}\rightarrow \delta(t-\tau)$? If it were, such integral becomes
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\kappa/2
\end{equation}
where we have used that $\int_{-\infty}^t\delta(t-\tau) d\tau=1/2$ because of the upper limit.

$\bullet$ $\kappa \rightarrow 0$

In this case, we cannot assume $e^{-\kappa |t-\tau|}\rightarrow \delta(t-\tau)$ anymore and we have to deal with the full integral. While there can be cases where it would be a problem, it is for me. Specifically, my function $f(x)$ is a superoperator, or in other words, a matrix. Are there any approximations I could make here? Some Taylor expansion around $\kappa=0$? Are they justified?

Comment: No you can't assume $e^{-\kappa\, |t-\tau|}\rightarrow \delta(t-\tau)$ as $\kappa\to\infty$. This is incorrect. Note $\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-\kappa\, |t|} \, dt=\frac{2}{\kappa}\to0$ as $\kappa\to\infty$, whereas $\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } \delta(t) \, dt=1$.

Comment: I see, but with the $\kappa$ in front of it, the $\kappa$ does cancel out. Moreover, I made some plots of the function and as $\kappa\rightarrow \infty$, it becomes more and more sharp, like a delta function.

Comment: $\delta(x)=\underset{\varepsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\ \frac{1}{2\, \varepsilon}\, e^{-\frac{|x|}{\varepsilon}}$ is a valid limit representation (see [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/0003/)), so substituting $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{\kappa}$ illustrates $\delta(x)=\underset{\kappa\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \frac{\kappa}{2} \,e^{-\kappa\, |x|}$ is also a valid limit representation.